# Safe way to generically allocate memory in Cocoa which will be automatically deallocated

Tags: xcode, cocoa, memory, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

In my Cocoa project I had a bunch of places where I used malloc/free. However several months ago I decided to refactor to leverage ARC and in order to do that I tried to make a replacement for malloc which will return a pointer to something that will be automatically cleaned up.

I used this function (error checking and other logging omitted)

```
+ (void *) MallocWithAutoCleanup: (size_t) size 
{
    NSMutableData * mutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:size];
    void * data = [mutableData mutableBytes];
    return data;
}
```

This worked fine for awhile, but recently a random memory overwrite issue came up. I tracked down the cause to this function, what appears to be happening is the NSMutableData instance is being deallocated even though I am keeping a pointer to its mutableBytes.

I guess this is happening because the only *direct* reference to the object is local and is going away, and the mutableBytes points inside the object so the ARC isn't smart enough to deal with that sort of reference counting.

Is there any way I can refactor this code to retain the mutableData object as long as the mutableBytes pointer is being used (i.e. someone has a reference to it)? I know one option is to just return the NSMutableData itself, but that requires some heavy refactoring and seems very messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you answered your own question. If you want to use `NSData` to manage generic memory allocations, you need to keep a reference to the `NSData` objects around until you're done with the memory it owns, at which point you nil out your reference(s) to the NSData object in question. This doesn't seem to provide any advantage compared to just manually freeing the malloced memory. Personally, I'd continue to use malloc()/free() explicitly instead of trying to contort my code in such a way that ARC kind of sort of manages malloced memory.

Either that, or I'd write my code such that it doesn't have to use malloc/free in the first place. I'd say the typical "pure" Cocoa project doesn't have many, if any, explicit malloc() calls, and I'd be a little suspicious of code that did unless there was some good reason for it. Why are you using malloc() in the first place?

Comment: I simply have a need to allocate memory for pre-existing C structures   . Malloc would be a fine fit, except that I have to really be careful of when I do the explicit free. Since ARC is designed to free things when they are no longer needed, I thought it would be the perfect way to address this problem. At present I am considering rewriting my objects to carry a pointer to the original NSMutableData object (instead of or in addition to) the original mutableBytes pointer. This should work fine.

Comment: ARC isn't really designed to free things when they're no longer needed, it simply automates Objective-C reference counting. ARC itself has no concept of "remaining references", that's handled by the reference _counting_ system at runtime, and only works for Objective-C objects. malloced memory doesn't have a reference count. Anyway, carrying a (strong) reference to the NSMutableData object in any object that needs access to the underlying, previously malloced memory seems like a good solution that essentially allows you to use ObjC reference counting, and therefor ARC, for your purposes.

Answer (score 9):

In the 10.7 SDK, `-[NSMutableData mutableBytes]` is decorated with the `NS_RETURNS_INNER_POINTER` attribute.  This signals to the compiler that the method returns a pointer whose validity depends on the receiver still existing.  What exactly ARC does with this is open to change, but currently it retains and autoreleases the receiver (subject to redundant operations being optimized away).

So, the pointer is valid for the duration of the current autorelease pool's lifetime.  This is akin to `-[NSString UTF8String]` (which is decorated in the same way).

ARC is not capable of keeping the mutable data object alive so long as there's any reference to the byte pointer. ARC is not a garbage collector. It doesn't watch all uses of all pointers. It operates locally. It examines one given function, method, or block and emits retains and releases for the behavior of the code as indicated by naming conventions. (Remember that ARC is interoperable with code which hasn't been compiled with ARC support.)

Since a `void*` isn't an object pointer and can't be retained or released, ARC can't do anything with it. So, in the code *calling* your `-MallocWithAutoCleanup:` method, ARC doesn't see anything it can manage. It doesn't emit any special memory management code. (What *could* it emit at that point?) While compiling the caller, the compiler likely doesn't know anything about the method implementation or the mutable data object inside it.

Think about it another way: if you were still writing manually reference counting code, what would you do in the caller of your method to keep the pointer valid? For the most part (ignoring `__weak` references), all ARC does is automatically do what you would do manually. Once you consider that you would have no options in that case, you realize that neither does ARC.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I thought that it should be theoretically possible for ARC to keep track of the pointer to the object's raw bytes and only deallocate the NSMutableData when this pointer goes away. But it sounds like ARC doesn't go that far since it isn't really a garbage-collector per-say.

Comment: @Ken I understand this case where the NSMutableData is a local variable.  However, I have it as a property of a class, and access the mutable data the same way inside a long loop and occasionally it will crash on EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the pointer back to the mutabledata.  However, the mutabledata is still there.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you changing the length of the data object? If you do, that can invalidate the byte pointer.